# Opening Activity from custom scheme not working in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: android, deep-linking, url-scheme

I have an app wherein I want to open one of its `Activities` through a custom scheme. Here is my activity in the Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.ResetPasswordActivity">
    <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="monicaaa" android:host="reg"
            android:pathPrefix="/password/reset/confirm"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In iOs, I can open the particular screen on the app by simply clicking on the link from my Gmail: `monicaaa://reg/password/reset/confirm/`, but in Android, I can only open the `ResetPasswordActivity` through Firefox mobile browser. It does not work in Chrome, it does not work in the default browser. Just Firefox.

I have read that Google no longer allows opening custom schemes, instead I must write my link as such:

```
intent://reg/password/reset/confirm/#Intent;schema=monicaaa;package=com.monicalabbao.monicaaa;end
```

But then it doesn't work at any browser at all.

Please tell me what I am missing, or if there had been existing answers, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `http`/`https` after all, like so:

```
https://reg/password/reset/confirm/
```

This enables the link to become clickable in Android Gmail, and it can lead to my app.

Answer (score 2):

You have a very small typographical error in your link: you used schema instead of scheme.

`intent://reg/password/reset/confirm/#Intent;schema=monicaaa;package=com.monicalabbao.monicaaa;end`

should be

`intent://reg/password/reset/confirm/#Intent;scheme=monicaaa;package=com.monicalabbao.monicaaa;end`

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it, but still it doesn't work anywhere else except Firefox.